# compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 18) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 19)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, build.gradle, javacompiler

```
compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 18) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 19) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
```

Doesn't Java have backward compatibility? because of a library I had to use java 18 in a project but I updated my jdk to 19 while ago. I shouldn't get this error, should I?

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you get the error again,
You can add the below lines inside build.gradle.kts(App level)

```
 android {
        ----
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
 kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(8)
  }
 }
```